# Failed Name Resolution for Redshift endpoint from Customer Client Machine

Tags: amazon-redshift

We failed to connect Redshift Endpoint from customer's client machine with below message;

```
FAILED!
[Amazon][Amaxon Redshift](10) Error occurred while trying to connect:[SQLState 08S01] could not translate host name "XXXX.XXXX.ap-northeast-1.redshift.amazoneaws.com" to address : Unknown server error
```

It seems like name resolution error. 
We can connect it, when we set the current(tentative) IP address of Redshift cluster, instead of Redshift Endpoint -- we get that IP address by nslookup command for Redshift Endpoint executed at EC2 instance, where we can normally success to connect to Redshift Endpoint.

As you know, above tetative solution is not good idea, since Redshift cluster IP address should be changed by cluster reboot or something, so We'd like to connect it by Redshift Endpoint. We understand some setting should be missing at our customer's client machine, but so far no idea what should we do.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.
Best regards.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Did you find a resolution?

Comment: @programmerj, sorry for my late reply.  We still have the same issue. At least, we can connect  to Redshift using IP address, it can be changed after reboot the cluster though.  If we'll find the solution, let me update it here.

Comment: I added a CNAME to Route 53 that points to the Redshift cluster hostname.  We are now able to connect out clients via ODBC and JDBC drivers using the CNAME value.

Comment: @programmerj I really appreciated your valuable information. We’ll try it ! Have a wonderful day :)